# c# Access specific class with Enum GetName

Tags: c#, enums

RootObject.cs

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public Class1 Class1 { get; set; }
        public Class2 Class2 { get; set; }
        public Class3 Class3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Class1.cs (Class2, Class3, ....)

```
    public class Class1
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
    }
```

Enum.cs

```
public enum Classes
{
    Class1,
    Class2,
    Class3
}
```

MyFunction.cs

```
nItemCount = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Classes)).Length;  /* equal to 3 */

for (i=0 ; i < nItemCount; i++)
{
    string name = RootObject.(Enum.GetName(typeof(Classes), i)).name;
}
```

I want to get the name value of Class1, Class2, Class3, etc. like a method above.

I wish I could explain my problem.

I need a solution for accessing all classes in a loop with the enum value.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Please name your variables better. `RootObject.strSubclass /* should return me RootObject.Class2 */` Do you want the class or do you want the variable?

Comment: Do you want to access the actual properties in RootObject with the help of the enum, or do you want to get hold of type objects, such as typeof(Class1)? (I guess, you are looking for the former, but i am not certain...)

Comment: I want to access the actual properties with the help of the enum. Like RootObject.Class2.someVariable

Comment: I 've detailed my question. Waiting for help. Thank you.

Comment: @eopariltay, note that `name` and `surname` are **instance** properties - they exist only in **instance objects** of type `Class1`. Trying to access them without having such an **instance object** makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @eopariltay, ah, i see your latest edit now. Now i understand...

Comment: i think you need use reflection [getproperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.getproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) and [getvalue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your code to be like below. Note I have used `Classes` as datatype for the Property.

```
public class RootObject
    {
        public Classes ClassProp { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Classes
    {
        Class1,
        Class2,
        Class3
    }
```

And then you can access the properties by using following code. You will have to instantiate the class and then access the property as they are Object level properoties and not static. Also, note that you will have to set the properties to get the appropriate enum value.

```
RootObject rootObj = new RootObject();
rootObj.ClassProp = Classes.Class2;
var class2 = rootObj.ClassProp;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: I updated the answer to make it easier to understand(changed property name etc.) ... Looks like he is just trying to figure out how to use enum properties.

Answer (score 0):

First, if all of your types Class1, Class2, Class3, ..., ClassWhatNot share same property definitions, it is better to move these same property definitions into a common **BaseClass** which the aforementioned classes will inherit from.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
}

class Class1 : BaseClass
{
    ...
}

class Class2 : BaseClass
{
    ...
}

//... do the definition of Class3 in the same way
```

Implement the **RootClass** as follows (note that i changed the names a bit to make it clearer how things work):

```
class RootClass
{
    public enum PropertyEnum
    {
        propClass1,
        propClass2,
        propClass3
    }

    public Class1 propClass1 { get; set; }
    public Class2 propClass2 { get; set; }
    public Class3 propClass3 { get; set; }

    public BaseClass GetPropertyByEnum(RootClass.PropertyEnum enumValue)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = typeof(RootClass).GetProperty(enumValue.ToString());
        return pi.GetValue(instance, null) as BaseClass;
    }
}
```

With the method *GetPropertyByEnum*  you can easily do:

```
RootClass rootObj = ...create/get the root object

foreach(RootClass.PropertyEnum enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RootClass.PropertyEnum))
{
    BaseClass b = rootObj.GetPropertyByEnum(enumValue);
    if (b != null) Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}.name = {1}", enumValue.ToString(), b.Name);
}
```

Note, that when not using a common base class (such as *BaseClass* in my example), *GetPropertyByName* could only return references of type `Object`. In such a case you would need to know how to cast the returned object to the appropriate type, which would make the whole endeavour of accessing properties by enum mostly pointless...

Answer (score 0):

If your classes share common members, either move those to a common base class or let the classes implement a common interface (or both).

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    public Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string Profession { get; set; }
}
```

Then, instead of creating individual properties for each the classes, add them to an array and use the enum values as index:

```
public enum PersonType
{
    Customer = 0,
    Employee = 1,
    Supplier = 2
}

public class RootObject
{
    Person[] _persons = new Person[] {
        new Customer(),
        new Employee(),
        new Supplier()
    };

    public Person[] Persons { get { return _persons; } }
}
```

Now you can access the persons easily with

```
foreach (PersonType personType in (PersonType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(PersonType))) {
    Person p = rootObject.Persons[(int)personType];
    string name = p.Name;
    string surname = p.Surname;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. That is very good example but I've one last problem. I'm getting response from a JSON call and the class instances are already created by a JSON parser. If I create a new Customer() or something like that, I'm losing assigned values. I have to create an array of current instances. How can I do that?

Comment: Like this: `Person[] _persons = new Person[] {
        currentInstance1,
        currentInstanc2,
        currentInstance3
    };` or you can create an empy array, or - if you don't know its length in advance - a `List<Person>` and fill it afterwadrs: `Person[] array = new array[3]; array[0] = x; array[1] = y;` etc. or: `List<Person> list = new List<Person>(); list.Add(x); list.Add(y);`